# Ruby Fibonacci Multiplication Table

Tags: ruby, sinatra, fibonacci

Ruby Fibonacci Multiplication Table *This was an interview question.*

Recently jumped into software development, and came across this challenge. Can you show me below, how can I write the Fibonacci multiplication table in Ruby language? For the last couple of days, I was trying to implement it but seems like I am facing a brick wall and the code makes me feel insane and also I failed on the interview, but that does not matter at the moment. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thanks a lot.

[image: screenshot]

**ApplicationController:**

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

    configure do
        set :public_folder, 'public'
        set :views, 'app/views'
    end
    
    get '/' do
        @time_of_day = Time.now
        erb :index
    end
    
end
```

**FibonacciController:**

```
class FibonacciController < ApplicationController

    get '/fibonacci' do
        place = params[:place].to_i
        @sequence = fib(place)
        erb :fibonacci
    end

    def fib(place)
        res = []
        a = 0
        b = 1
        
        while b < place do
        res << b         
        a,b = b,a+b
        end
        
        res 
    end

end
```

**Fibonacci.erb**

```
<div class="container">
<h1> Fibonacci sequence: </h1>
    <div class="sub-container">
        <p> Generated fibonacci sequence: </p> 
        <%= @sequence.join(', ') %>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Index.erb**

```
<div class="container">
    Date and time: <%= @time_of_day %>
    <br>
    <h1> Fibonacci Multiplication Table </h1>
    <p> Enter your number below: </p>

    <form method="GET" action="/fibonacci">
        <label for="sequence">
        <input type="integer" name="place" placeholder="Insert your number">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    
</div>
```

(This is the ultimate goal of this challenge)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**FibonacciController code**

```
class FibonacciController < ApplicationController

  get '/fibonacci' do
    place = params[:place].to_i
    sequence = fib(place)
    @table = generate_table(sequence)
    erb :fibonacci
  end

  def fib(place)
    return [] if place <= 0

    a = 0
    b = 1
    res = [a]

    while res.length < place do
      res << b
      a,b = b, a+b
    end

    res 
  end

  def generate_table(sequence)
    return [] if sequence.length.zero?

    cols = []
    (sequence.length + 1).times do |row|
      row_data = []
      (sequence.length + 1).times do |col|
        row_data << generate_table_element(row, col, sequence)
      end
      cols << row_data
    end
    cols
  end

  def generate_table_element(row, col, sequence)
    return '_' if row.zero? && col.zero?
    return sequence[col - 1] if row.zero?
    return sequence[row - 1] if col.zero?

    sequence[col - 1] * sequence[row - 1]
  end

end
```

And in **erb file**

```
<p> Generated fibonacci sequence: </p> 
<% @table.each do |table_row| %>
  <%= table_row.join(',') %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```